# Vue-router doesn't redirect to page after checking if value exists

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router, store

Good day. I am trying to create a guard to my Vue application that only redirects to a page if a value in a state exists (not null or undefined). However when I use `beforeEnter` I get a circular reference and it doesn't redirect me to the page.  If I use `beforeRouteEnter` I am redirected normally but if I updated the page I am not redirect to the previous page.  What exactly is wrong here method can redirect me to the page after checking a store state?

The method in the store is very simple and I simply save whatever comes from the api call in my state, which starts out as null. What exactly is wrong here?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import form'@/components/form.vue'
import values'@/components/values.vue'
import store from '@/store.js'


Vue.use(VueRouter)
const routes = [
    { 
        path: '/', 
        component: form
    },
    { 
        path: '/values', 
        component: values,
        beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
            guard(to, from, next)
        },
    }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})

const guard = function(to, from, next){
    let info = store.getters.result
    if(info){
        next('/values')
    } else {
        next('/')
    }
}

export default router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`beforeEnter`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) because [`beforeRouteEnter`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) is the name of the in-component hook and will not work there.  The reason you got a circular reference is that  `next('/values')` redirects to itself.  Change it to `next()` to tell the router to carry on with the current route with no redirect:

```js
const guard = function(to, from, next){
    let info = store.getters.result
    if(info){
        next()
    } else {
        next('/')
    }
}
```